# Share a (container)control from a (custom)control?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, containers, designer

Soo... I am making a control like the Windows Update "panels".
Everything's fine up to the "container" part.
What I want to do is to allow the designer to place controls in a `Panel` which is inside my control.
(The panel's variable is held in my control's class and inside the control itself.)

How do I bypass this?

As a reference, you might want to **try out** this [AeroWizard Control](http://aerowizard.codeplex.com/), which does this pretty well.
(Yes, I have looked at it and didn't find a clue but custom designers!)

As a side note, I'd rather **not** make a complicated designer class...

Comment: For completing this, I ended up with two more classes in my file - the designer and a custom `ContainerControl` to hold the controls right.  But at least it works. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>If you don't want to create a custom designer class, you should implement your control as a [templated custom control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478964.aspx), preferably inheriting from [CompositeControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.compositecontrol.aspx).</strike>

There doesn't seem to be a way to do the same in Windows Forms without a custom designer class. However, there's a nice, short, working example of such a designer [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdesigner/thread/df923990-f739-491b-85cc-0636ddc9f0fb).

Comment: No no no, I am programming for WinForms, not ASP.NET! I forgot to add the tag... Now it's fixed. :) And thanks anyway for the answer!

Comment: Sorry, since you mentioned `UpdatePanel` I assumed `ASP.NET`. I'll see what I can do :)

Comment: Windows Update "panels" - the panels used in Windows Vista and Windows 7 in programs such as Windows Update. They feature a strip on the left side colored to show some status, an icon next to the strip and a "main instruction" as text.   By the way, I call it TaskPanel. :D